# POST/GET array is empty, after form submit

Tags: php, forms

I've tried my code with POST and GET method also, but I can't see any value of these methods. After submit the form the page is refreshing but my .php file write out this: `Array ( )`

I was looking for the value in Chrome developer tools but there is no 'Form data' inside the network tab, just general, response headers and request headers.

[image]

My HTML code:

```
<!--Modal: Login Form-->
      <form id="loginModal" name="loginModal" class="modal fade modal-full-height" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
        data-backdrop="static" action="/main.php" method="POST">
          <div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal" role="document">
              <!--Content-->
              <div id="loginModalDiv" class="modal-content">
                  <!--Header-->
                  <div class="modal-header myModalHeader">
                      <h4 class="title"><i class="fa fa-user-lg"></i> Login:</h4>
                  </div>
                  <!--Body-->
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="md-form form-sm">
                          <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                          <input type="text" id="logF_email" name="email" class="form-control">
                          <label for="logF_email">E-mail address:</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="md-form form-sm">
                          <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                          <input type="password" id="logF_passw" name="password" class="form-control">
                          <label for="logF_passw ">Password:</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="text-center mt-2">
                          <div id="errorLogin"></div>
                          <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-default myModalBtn">Belépés <i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Footer-->
                  <div id="footerLogin" class="modal-footer">
                      <div class="options text-center text-md-center mt-1">
                          <p>You don't have an account? <a class="loginToSignUp myGreenClass" data-toggle="modal" href="#"> Sign up!</a></p>
                          <p>Forget <a class="forgetPassword myGreenClass" data-toggle="modal" href="#"> password?</a></p>
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-default waves-effect ml-auto myModalBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!--/.Content-->
          </div>
      </form>
```

...and the .php file:

```
$email =""; $password ="";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    print_r($_POST);
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    print_r($email);
    print_r($password);
    if ($email=="") {echo "<br> 'no data'";}
        else        {echo "Your email: ".$email;}
  }
```

I'm beginner in PHP, and form-handling, so I think I could miss something.
I tried to avoid the trivial mistakes, therefor my code contains:

- action and method proprty for form
- name attribute for input fields
- `type="submit"` for submit button

`if ( $_POST ){`
`if (!empty($_POST)){`

**also not working**

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: change method="GET" to method="post"

Comment: It is post, i just try get and post also.

Comment: none of them work

Comment: I mean if i change in php and html to post

Comment: all the answers below are exactly the same ;)

Comment: @G4bor try printing $_REQUEST before if and see the output.

Comment: Are that all request headers? Seems like there isn't any data posted..

Comment: same: Array ( )

Comment: yes, no more headers. I think about the same, but I don't know why?

Comment: why is the data not sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, **I've found the error!**

Before I sent the value I validated the data with jQuery inside the submit function.

```
$("#loginModal").submit(function(){
...
```

The problem is that I've disabled the form before submitting it because I wanted to make some precautionary measure to the user won't be able to do anything until the server not respond. 
(e.g.: long waiting time if the connection is slow)

```
...
$('#loginModalDiv *').prop('disabled',true);
$('#footerLogin').hide();
return true;}
```

When I cut the last two line out before the return, (so the form stay enabled) the submit function became capable to send the data from the input fields.

**Conclusion:**
So,... for everybody who don't know (like me before), the POST and GET method not send any data from a disabled part(like a < div >) of a form.
Hmmm... good to know! :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your form method from `GET` to `POST` as your backend is filtering on the POST method.

Comment: I've tried post and get, and forget to set back, by the way none of them working

Answer (score 2):

In your form tag method is `GET` it should be `POST`. If you do not mention method it will take `GET` method automatically. So you want get data from `POST` then you should use `POST` method in form tag. Remove `GET` from the form tag.

```
<form id="loginModal" name="loginModal" class="modal fade modal-full-height" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
        data-backdrop="static" action="/main.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: I've tried post and get, and forget to set back, by the way none of them working

Comment: are you click back button after form submission?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: On the form there are two inputs for email and password. I validated them in javascript, and I want to do the same in php then check it in database. Actually a complete login and signup procedure for a web app.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method of the form to post in place of get

```
method="GET"
```

to

```
method="post"
```

As in backend you looking for request method as post. In frontend and backend both needs to be same.

Comment: I've tried post and get, and forget to set back, by the way none of them working